# IE10 currentTarget javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, target

I have a problem with event.currentTarget on IE 10.

I have two divs on the website. One div contains img which size is on full screen. Second div is smaller and placed on the first div. Smaller cointains nothing. It has only width, height, top, left attributes. When i trigger currentTarget on click, it doesnt see the smaller div but only the bigger one. Even when i click right mouse button and choose option check element it only find the bigger div. This situation is fixed when I set for example background-color to the smaller div.

This situation takes place only on IE10. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Your description is unclear. What do you mean by "trigger currentTarget on click"? currentTarget is not something you trigger, it is a property of Event instances. It references the EventTarget instance (usually a DOM Node) whose listener is currently reacting to the event.

Comment: also, what do you mean by "second div is […] on the first div"? is the second div a child of the first, or is it merely displayed over it using some CSS?

Comment: @Touffy I mean I attached to divs click handler which logs event.currentTarget. The divs are on the same level in DOM.

Comment: OK. So both divs have an event listener for 'click', and you have a practically invisible div that's supposed to be on top of (part of) the other, and the invisible div is effectively unclickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that this is indeed a know problem with IE: [Empty div hover event not firing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158921/empty-div-hover-event-not-firing-in-ie)

You should try a solution that was found to work in that case: fully transparent background-image.