# Display text overlay and apply image transparency on hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an image semitransparent on hover and display text that is otherwise set to `display: none`. Currently if you hover over an image, it becomes semi-transparent (`.single-image:hover` works), but the text doesn't appear. When the text was not set to `display: none`, it is positioned over the image in the bottom left-hand corner. I thought that since it is over the image, the hover pseudo-class would take effect. I also tried setting the z-index of `.attribution` to 1 but that didn't do anything.

```
<div className="image-container">
    <a href={image.links.html} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
       <img className="single-image" src={image.urls.regular} alt="" />
       <p className="attribution">Unsplash</p>
    </a>
 </div>
```

```
    .image-container {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    /* Text */
    .attribution {
      display: none;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 20px;
    }

    .attribution:hover {
      display: block;
    }

    .single-image {
      margin: 7px;
      height: 350px;
      width: 350px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .single-image:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `hover` function to the parent div.

Change `.attribution:hover` to `.image-container:hover .attribution` and `.single-image:hover` to `.image-container:hover .single-image`.

Strangely enough, in order for this to work, you also need to add border or background-color to your parent div. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158921/empty-div-hover-event-not-firing-in-ie) is why)

I added a transparent color `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`.

```css
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Text */
.attribution {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.image-container:hover .attribution {
  display: block;
}

.single-image {
  margin: 7px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-container:hover .single-image {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
       <img class="single-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" alt="" />
       <p class="attribution">Kitten!</p>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should also change `className` to `class` if you are not using a framework to do that already. I added a code snippet in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cont { 
    position: relative; 
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.layer { 
    position: relative; 
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    color: Transparent;
}
.layer:hover { color: white; }
.cont:hover { background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="layer">My cool Text</div>
</div>
```

Why did you not set the color of the font to transparent? it's easyer. see my little example (2 minutes workaround...)

Answer (score 0):

Add a bit of javascript to make the text appear aswell as the image fade.
as only one element can be in hover state even if there ontop of each other. 
unless you mess around with js you might be able to 'hack' a double hover state.

try;

```
    <div className="image-container">
      <a href={image.links.html} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img className="single-image" src={image.urls.regular} alt="" />
        <p className="attribution">Unsplash</p>
      </a>
    </div>

.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  }

/* Text */
.attribution {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:3;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  }
.single-image {
  margin: 7px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index:2;
  }

.single-image:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  will-change:opacity;
  }

    <script>
    document.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded,(e)=>{
    const img = document.getElementsByClassName('single-image')[0];
    const attrib = document.getElementsByClassName('attribution')[0]; 

     img.addEventListener('mouseover',(e)=>{
        img.style.opacity = '0.7';
        attrib.style.display = 'block';
     });

    });
    </script>
```